# React Router Dom V6 pass array to path

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to render same page by multiple routes in react-router-dom v6 like how it was in v5.
However, I couldn't find a efficient way to do it.

Example in v5 I can do this:

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={["/dashboard", "/home"]} render={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/other" render={<OtherPage/>} />
        <Route path={["/", "/404"]} render={<NotFound />} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

But in v6, it is said that the `path` needs to be a **string**.

The only way I found that can achieve this is to separate them as follow:

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Which means I have to write `<Home />` **multiple times**.

I want to keep my code as CLEAN as possible.

I checked the official [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5), but didn't mention about this part. And I did research, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: In v6 you're right, path must be a string. You could use a `map` function over the array of routes... however if you want your code to be as "CLEAN" as possible, why have two routes that go to the same component? That isn't clean.

Comment: Check the type declaration [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route) and indeed the `path` is only allowed to be a string type.

Comment: @MikeAbeln Great point, `map` does figure the trick. Thanks for pointing that out. But if I have to do so, I'd rather downgrade to v5. And personally, passing an array into path rather than write the similar wrapper components twice (or use `map`) is much more CLEAN to me.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, that's why I'm asking for solution which I could achieve my goal with a simple and efficient approach

Comment: Oh, sorry, was more just confirming with Mike that in v6 it is currently typed to not take an array of path strings. I hadn't noticed that yet so I was also a little surprised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created this helper function and it works in React Router v6:

```js
const renderMultiRoutes = ({ element: Element, paths, ...rest }: MultiRoutes) =>
  paths.map((path) => <Route key={path} path={path} {...rest} element={Element} />);
```

Then I can do the following:

```
<Routes>
  {renderMultiRoutes({
    paths: ['/', '/dashboard'],
    element: <Feature />,
  })}
</Routes>
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

There is no need for custom solutions. The cleanest solution is to loop internally:

```
<Routes>
  {["/dashboard", "/home"].map(path => (
    <Route 
      key="Home" // optional: avoid full re-renders on route changes
      path={path}
      element={<Home />}
    />
  ))}
</Routes>
```

For your use case with only two routes, I personally think having separate routes is more readable. But for my use case; where I have 6+ routes pointing to the same component, it doesn't make sense any longer.

#### Key prop

The fixed `key` is a "hack" that's only needed for specific cases where your users have a way to switch between the URLs internally and/or if the component is heavy. Using the same `key` for all routes in the Array tells React that the component didn't unmount when React Router switches routes and that only the props changed, this way React doesn't re-render the entire branch. It works because React Router v6 never renders two routes at any point in time.

#### Playground

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-otdpok?file=src/App.tsx

Comment: it's a shame the upgrade documentation doesn't cover cases like this

Answer (score 1):

As a result I downgraded to v5.
However, here is a solution based on @MikeAbeln's point `map`.
I built a wrapper component to do the trick.

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function MultiRoute({ element: Element, path: paths, ...rest }) {
    return (
        <>
            {Array.isArray(paths) ? paths.map((path) =>
                <Route path={path} {...rest} element={props => <Element {...props} />} />
            ) :
                <Route path={paths} {...rest} element={props => <Element {...props} />} />
            }
        </>
    );
}
```

Then I can do as follow to make my Routes.js file CLEAN enough and easy scale:

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <MultiRoute path={["/dashboard", "/home"]} element={<Home />} />
        <MultiRoute path="/other" element={<OtherPage/>} />
        <MultiRoute path={["/", "/404"]} element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

**UPDATE**

This will return an Error "Error: [MultiRoute] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>" as @Drew Reese mentioned. **Needs to be fixed**.

Kindly comment below or leave an answer and thanks in advance.

Comment: I was skeptical at first, but decided to [give it a try anyway](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-v6-pass-array-to-path-n55mc), the v6 code unfortunately still throws "Error: [MultiRoute] is not a `<Route>` component. All component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`".

Comment: Oh. Thank you for giving it a try tho, and I'm sorry I didn't even try after building that code. I'll mark it as "needs to be improved" open for others to fix, but I don't want to spend more time digging into this.

Comment: I don't think there's much to dig on, the new `Routes` and `Route` synergy is pretty coupled and the code does some strict invariant testing. Only `Route` components can be children of `Routes`, and only `Routes` can be parent of `Route`.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, I just simply turned back to v5. But if there is an answer in the future, it will be good to move forward instead of backward.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation. I have some different routes that should render same page layout. In v5 it was implemented as:

```
<Switch>
    <Route
      exact
      path={[
        ROOT_ROUT,
        SIGN_UP_ROUT,
        FORGOT_PASSWORD_ROUT,
        CHANGE_FORGOT_PASSWORD_ROUT,
      ]}
    >
      <AuthPageTemplate>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
          <Route exact path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
          <Route exact path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/change-forgot-password/:code"
            component={ChangeForgotPassword}
          />
        </Switch>
      </AuthPageTemplate>
    </Route>
    <Route component={Page404} />
  </Switch>
```

And after update this code solves the same task:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={
      <AuthPageTemplate>
        <Outlet />
      </AuthPageTemplate>
    }
  >
    <Route index element={<SignIn />} />
    <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
    <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
    <Route
      path="/change-forgot-password/:code"
      element={<ChangeForgotPassword />}
    />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<Page404 />} />
</Routes>
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

**For me this worked for react-router-dom v6**

```
<Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Navigate to="/search" />} />
    <Route exact path='/videos' element={<Results />} />
    <Route exact path='/news' element={<Results />} />
    <Route exact path='/images' element={<Results />} />
    <Route exact path='/search' element={<Results />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: `exact` has been removed from `Route` in v6

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem creating a project:
The simple solution is to map over all paths:

#### Here is the Solution:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={["/videos", "/images","/news"]} render={<Result />} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Now we have to convert this code into `react-router-dom` v6:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {['/images','/videos','/news'].map(path => (
          <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Result />}
))}
      </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{["/exstv", "/exstv/:id"]?.map((item) => {
    return <Route path={item} element={<SportsTv />}></Route>
 })}
```